# Копирование файлов в папку с ограничением в 100МБ

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь скопировать (массив расширений файлов) в папку ( и в эту папку которую я копирую сделать ограничение в **100МБ**), если лимит превышен файлов в папке, прекратить копировать!
Вот код:

```
public static void GetFilesList()
{
    long DS = 1000000;
    string[] extens = 
    { 
    ".txt", ".doc", 
    ".cs", ".ico", 
    ".Dll", ".Html", 
    ".Htm", ".Xml", 
    ".Php", ".png", 
    ".jpg", ".gif" 
    };
    if (DirSize(new DirectoryInfo(Easy.GooVer), DS) > DS)
    {
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(Easy.GooVer, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            if (Array.IndexOf(extens, ext) >= 0)
            { try{
              File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(Easy.str1, Path.GetFileName(fileName)), true);}catch { }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d, long aLimit = 0)
{
    long Size = 0;
    FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
    {
        Size += fi.Length;
        if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
            return Size;
    }
    DirectoryInfo[] dis = d.GetDirectories();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dis)
    {
        Size += DirSize(di, aLimit);
        if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
            return Size;
    }
    return (Size);
}
```

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: А почему у вас `if (DirSize(new DirectoryInfo(Easy.GooVer), DS) > DS)`? Вы уверены насчёт `>`?

Comment: @Monk, Во время копирование файлов в папку сделать ограничение. Если папка превышает допустимый размер 100МБ, то завершить копирование файлов в папку)))

Comment: Просто сохраните текущий размер в переменную, перед копированием файла прибавляйте к ней его размер и проверяйте, не превышен ли лимит. Только не забудьте вычитать размер в `catch {}` на случай, если скопировать файл не удалось (хотя лучше, наверное, будет проверять, существует ли вообще скопированный файл, и если да, проверять его размер).

Comment: @VladD, я предположил сделать проверку через цикл `while(true)`,но видимо не канает, я уже не знаю куда плыть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно эту задачу решить через паттерн **ИТЕРАТОР**, хотя может это будет и сложнее и больше писанины, но ведь это же классика!

Нам понадобиться `Enumerator`

```
internal class FilesEnumerator : IEnumerator<FileInfo>
{
    private string _StartPath;
    private IEnumerator<string> _FileEnumerator;

    //ctor
    public FilesEnumerator(string startPath, string searchPattern)
    {
        _StartPath = startPath;

        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_StartPath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        _FileEnumerator = files.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public FileInfo Current
    {
        get
        {
            return new FileInfo(_FileEnumerator.Current);
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Current;
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return _FileEnumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _FileEnumerator.Reset();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _FileEnumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

далее локатор

```
public class FilesLocator : IEnumerable<FileInfo>
{
    private string _StartPath;
    private string _SearchPattern;

    //ctor
    public FilesLocator(string startPath, string searchPattern = "*.*")
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(startPath)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(startPath)} не может быть пустым");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(startPath)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(searchPattern)} не может быть пустым");

        _StartPath = startPath;
        _SearchPattern = searchPattern;
    }

    public IEnumerator<FileInfo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new FilesEnumerator(_StartPath, _SearchPattern);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Ну, а пользоваться можно так

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void FilesLocatorTest()
    {
        string fromC = @"D:\Temp";
        string toC = @"C:\Temp";
        //вы уж извините, я тут свои другие расширения подставил
        List<string> extensions = new List<string>() { ".json", ".txt" };
        //опять же можете др. лимит прописать
        long limit = 100000;

        var files = new FilesLocator(fromC);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(file.Name);
            int id = extensions.IndexOf(ext);
            if ( id < 0) continue;

            if ((limit -= file.Length) < 0) break;

            try
            {
                file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(toC, file.Name));
            }
            catch
            {
                //
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
long copiedSoFar = 0;
foreach (string fileName in
             Directory.GetFiles(Easy.GooVer, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    if (Array.IndexOf(extens, ext) < 0)
        continue;
    try
    {
        var fileSize = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
        if (copiedSoFar + fileSize > DS)
            continue; // другие файлы могут ещё влезть
        File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(Easy.str1, Path.GetFileName(fileName)), true);
        copiedSoFar += fileSize;
    }
    catch
    {
        // тут надо сделать что-то разумное
    }
}
```

Comment: А что по поводу `while(true)`, у меня просто есть сомнения что он проверку не проведёт)), ну я попробую, спс).

Comment: Пробуйте, должно работать по идее.

Comment: Попробовал Ваш метод, файлы копируются только с 1 директории, не по всем папкам проходит.

Comment: @ArteS: Не может быть, вы не забыли случайно `SearchOption.AllDirectories`? Покажите код, который вы пробовали.

Comment: @VladD, пробег по подпапкам есть, а вот восстановление структуры папок на новом месте - нет. Наверно это имеется в виду.

Comment: @Monk: Ну, хотелось бы, чтобы автор вопроса это сформулировал в вопросе.

Comment: @VladD внезапно, не надо. Тогда всё ок =)

Comment: @Monk: Я вот подумал, может, у ТС файлы с одинаковыми именами? Но он не говорит, в чём проблема.

Comment: @VladD, возможно молчаливый try-catch новичка сожрал вместе с ошибкой? =) В чате разбираемся, в новом вопросе. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50970/discussion-between-artes-and-monk